# Is it possible to use scrapy without Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, anaconda

So I am very new to scraping and trying to learn scrapy. Most of the tutorial on web I have seen use Anaconda for scrapy project. I just wish to know is it possible to use scrapy without Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's is normally possible,
You can download it with pip
check there : http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

you should probably use a dedicated virtualenv to avoid conflicting with your system packages.

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv Pipenv is a good one

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Following steps would lead you to that(if you're using Ubuntu):

1. Install python-pip if (if not installed)

   sudo apt-get install python 3-pip
2. Next install scrapy

   sudo pip install Scrapy

[How to install pip on Windows](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/)

 Step #2 still remains the same for Windows.

Cheers!